# Conditionally updating XML values

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to conditionally update a block of XML in a file. This is the target XML block

```xml
<Data Description="Runs a keyword test." TestName="MenuAction_DataDriver">
  <Parameters LangId="{897793E3-73F3-4895-A956-3D41D3A24A45}">
    <Parameter Name="FilePath" DefVarType="8" DefValueType="6" DefValueValue="Excel Workbooks\MenuAction.xlsx" VarType="8" ValueType="6" ValueValue="Excel Workbooks\MenuAction.xlsx" />
    <Parameter Name="Sheet" DefVarType="8" DefValueType="6" DefValueValue="Sheet1" VarType="8" ValueType="6" ValueValue="Sheet1" />
    <Parameter Name="Caller" DefVarType="8" DefValueType="6" DefValueValue="" VarType="8" ValueType="6" ValueValue="FileClose" />
  </Parameters>
</Data>
```

There are multiple ones like this, and other `<Data>` nodes that don't have these parameters. So I'm trying to iterate through a file, looking for `<Data>` nodes with a `TestName` property of "MenuAction_DataDriver", and then specifically looking for only these nodes where the `Parameter[2].ValueValue` is "FileClose". I am then looking to change the `Parameter[1].ValueValue` from "Sheet1" to "File".

This is the current attempt I've made at this:

```bsh
$xmlFileName = 'C:\<PathToFileRedacted>.tcKDTest'
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $xmlFileName
$xmldoc.Root.SelectSingleNode("//Data[@TestName='MenuAction_DataDriver']") |
    ? { $_.Parameters.Parameter.ValueValue[2] -eq 'FileClose'} |
    % {$_.Parameters.Parameter.ValueValue[1] = "File"}
$xmlDoc.Save($xmlFileName)
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix dot-access and XPath. You can use XPath to select exactly the node whose attribute you want to modify. You also probably don't want to select the nodes by index when you can use value matches to the same end.

```
$xpath = "//Data[@TestName='MenuAction_DataDriver']/Parameters[Parameter[@Name='Caller' and @ValueValue='FileClose']]/Parameter[@Name='Sheet']"

$node = $xmldoc.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
$node.ValueValue = 'File'
```

Breakdown of the XPath expression:

- `//Data[@TestName='MenuAction_DataDriver']` → select `<Data>` nodes anywhere in the XML document that have an attribute `TestName` with the value `MenuAction_DataDriver`.
- `/Parameters[Parameter[@Name='Caller' and @ValueValue='FileClose']]` → select a `<Parameters>` node that has a child node `<Parameter>` with an attribute `Name` with the value `Caller` and an attribute `ValueValue` with the value `FileClose`.
- `/Parameter[@Name='Sheet']` → select a node `<Parameter>` that has an attribute `Name` with the value `Sheet`.